# How to get a parameter from request symfony2

Tags: symfony, request, twig, dump

I can give you a part of the requests dump:

`{{ dump(requests) }}` :

```
 -route: "userBuyerProductRequestGetAll"
  -params: array:3 [
    "productRequestId" => null
    "sort" => "p.name"
    "direction" => "asc"
  ]
  -pageRange: 9
  -template: "dsarhoyaSCBundle:Layout:paginator.html.twig"
  -sortableTemplate: "dsarhoyaSCBundle:Layout:sortable_link.html.twig"
  -filtrationTemplate: "KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:filtration.html.twig"
  -extraViewParams: []
  #currentPageNumber: 1
  #numItemsPerPage: 20
  #items: array:20 [
    0 => ProductRequest {#1528
      -id: 165
      -originalRequestId: null
      -originalRequestDate: null
      -creationTime: DateTime {#1521
        +"date": "2015-11-12 12:29:49"
        +"timezone_type": 3
        +"timezone": "America/Santiago"
      }
      -quantity: "1.00"
      -dimension: null
      -brand: null
      -model: null
      -origin: null
      -requiresExample: null
      -processSuggestion: null
      -lastValidatedStep: 1
      -correlative: 5
      -deletedAt: null
      -assignedQuantity: "0.00"
      -status: "pending"
      -comments: "ASD"
      -unit: CompanyUnit {#452
        +__isInitialized__: true
        -id: 3
        -name: "agua-salada" <-- i need this
```

How can I reach the unit-name to be printed in a twig template?. I think is something like `{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') }}`, but it give me an error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template.

I had to do this:

```
{% set i=0 %}
{% for request in requests%}
    {% if i==0 %}
        {{request.unit.name}}
        {% set i=1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

it works but itsn't the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for :

```
{{ app.request.get('name') }}
```

Comment: Your question is not precise enought, what is exactly the `name` var ?

Comment: see my recent comment

Comment: Where is it located ?